# Get full address after picking autocomplete from getAddress library

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the [JavaScript - Autocomplete](https://documentation.getaddress.io/JavaScriptAutocomplete) library from  [getAddress.io](https://getaddress.io/).

My code is like below.

```js
getAddress.autocomplete(
    "formatted_address_0",
    "API_key",
    {
        output_fields:{
            formatted_address_0:'formatted_address_0',
        },
    }
);
```

I am getting below output in the Developers tools - network tab.

[image]

I would like to catch whole `formatted_address` array to show the whole address.

Comment: Please [edit] your title to something describing what you're trying to do. "Catch JSON Response" is to vague.

Comment: Thanks @0stone0. I know it is vague. But I couldn't find better title.

Comment: Something like "Get full address after picking autocomplete from getAddress library" might already be better.

Comment: Thanks @0stone0. Actually I was trying to catch JSON output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `getaddress-autocomplete-address-selected` event which get's the `formatted_address` array passed in the arguments.

Use `join()` to create a string an place that where ever you like.

---

Small demo, fill in your own API key, gif underneath

```js
getAddress.autocomplete(
    'autocomplete',
    'foo_bar_OrcVzqfg40211' 
);

document.addEventListener("getaddress-autocomplete-address-selected", (e) => {
    document.querySelector('#fill').textContent = e.address.formatted_address.join(' ');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.getaddress.io/scripts/getaddress-autocomplete-1.1.3.min.js"></script>

<label>Start typing</label>
<input id="autocomplete" type="text"> 

<br />
<em id='fill' />
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks @0stone0. `document.addEventListener("getaddress-autocomplete-address-selected", (e) => {
    document.querySelector('#fill').textContent = e.address.formatted_address.join(' ');
})`

This portion is not working.

Comment: can I use like this `getAddress.autocomplete(
            "formatted_address_0",
            "API_key",
            {
                output_fields:{
                    formatted_address_0:'formatted_address_0 formatted_address_1 formatted_address_2',
                },
            }
        );`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Thanks @0stone0. How can I concatenate all those ?

Comment: Thats what I'm showing in my answer? Use `join()` on the `formatted_address` that can be found in one of the events thrown by the librarby

Comment: Thanks @0stone0. But that `addEventListener` is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Well as you can see in the GIF, it's working here. So you must have something else. You could add a [mre] in your question to show the code that's not working. My javascript fills an element with the `id` `fill`, make sure to have that in your DOM if you're blindly copying my code.